# How to create RequestManager class without using frameworks swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsjsonserialization, jsonobjectrequest

I have created 5 classes which includes ProfileHomeModel, ProfileLocationModel, ProfileRequestManager, ProfileTableUserViewController and ProfileTableViewCell. My goal is to parse json correctly and display the data. I have run into a problem in my request manager class. I am totally new to swift. I would like to do this without using swiftyJSON and Alamofire.

```
import Foundation
class ProfileRequestManager{


    let urlPath = "*********"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

        print(jsonData)
        let results = jsonData!.objectForKey("strengths") as? [NSDictionary] ?? []

    for result in results {
        print(result)
    }


    }
    catch {
        print("Something went wrong while parsing json data fetched from the API")
    }


}
```

jsonData

`{
    "success": true,
    "profile": {
        "firstname": "Vignesh",
        "lastname": "Krish",
        "title": "Software Developer Intern",
        "designations": null,
        "specialty": "Computer Science",
        "location": "0",
        "email": "vignesh@ampthealth.com",
        "phone": "4026136265",
        "biography": "Boxing and Travelling",
        "interests": "Watching movies",
        "skills": "Hozier and  A.R Rahman",
        "goals": "becoming a software developer",
        "mentors": "Hardik Patel",
        "doh": "2016-05-09",
        "dob": "1994-06-08",
        "strengths": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "Analytical",
                "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Analytical theme search for reasons and causes. They have the ability to think about all the factors that might affect a situation.",
                "color": "9c0000"
            },
            {
                "id": "17",
                "name": "Focus",
                "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Focus theme can take a direction, follow through, and make the corrections necessary to stay on track. They prioritize, then act.",
                "color": "5c3a6e"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "Communication",
                "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Communication theme generally find it easy to put their thoughts into words. They are good conversationalists and presenters.",
                "color": "da892f"
            },
            {
                "id": "29",
                "name": "Responsibility",
                "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Responsibility theme take psychological ownership of what they say they will do. They are committed to stable values such as honesty and loyalty.",
                "color": "5c3a6e"
            },
            {
                "id": "30",
                "name": "Restorative",
                "description": "People exceptionally talented in the Restorative theme are adept at dealing with problems. They are good at figuring out what is wrong and resolving it.",
                "color": "5c3a6e"
            }
        ],
        "settings": {
            "enable_sms": "0"
        }
    }
}`

I'm trying to return all of it above

the error I'm getting is on the do catch. `Xcode` is giving me an expected declaration error. I checked my curly braces.

Would appreciate some help to figure this out.

Also, I need not include to url for security purposes. I hope it helps.

I am also trying to display all the values in separate cells. This is what I have now.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileUserTableViewCell
        cell.firstName?.text = firstName
        cell.lastName?.text = lastName
        cell.title?.text = title

        return cell

}
}
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

this is my current situation. I can't get it to display  on table view cells.
The problem seems to be with how I'm assigning my json values to the labels.

import UIKit

class ProfileUserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.reloadData()
    //retrieving json from server

    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https:******************")!

    //Your baseURL
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine")

            do {
                let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                guard let JSONDictionary :NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary else {
                    print("Not a Dictionary")

                    return
                }
                //  print("JSONDictionary! \(JSONDictionary)")

                if let profile = JSONDictionary["profile"] as? NSDictionary {
                    print(profile)
                    //This is where we should begin parsing json into whatever you want to
                    let firstName = profile["firstName"] as? String
                    let lastName = profile["lastName"] as? String
                    let title = profile["title"] as? String

                    print(firstName!, lastName, title!)

                    //                        let settings = profile["settings"] as? NSDictionary
                    //
                    //                        let enableSMS = settings!.valueForKey("enable_sms") as? String
                    //                        print(enableSMS!)

                    //to parse commentTotals content from api
                    let commentTotals = profile["commentTotals"] as? NSArray
                    for eachItem in commentTotals! {
                        let total = eachItem.valueForKey("total") as? String
                        let id = eachItem.valueForKey("id") as? String
                        print(total!,id!)

                    }

                    //to parse strength contents from api
                    let strengths = profile["strengths"] as? NSArray
                    for eachItem in strengths! {
                        let color = eachItem.valueForKey("color") as? String
                        let description = eachItem.valueForKey("description")
                        let id = eachItem.valueForKey("id")
                        let name = eachItem.valueForKey("name")
                        print(name!, description!, color!, id!)
                    }
                }
            }
            catch let JSONError as NSError {
                print("\(JSONError)")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileUserTableViewCell

        cell.firstName?.text = [indexPath.row].firstName
        cell.lastName?.text =  [indexPath.row].lastName
        cell.title?.text =  [indexPath.row].title



        return cell

    }

    if indexPath.row == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileUserTableViewCell

        cell.score?.text = [indexPath.row].score
        cell.received?.text =  [indexPath.row].received
        cell.given?.text =  [indexPath.row].given
        return cell

    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileCell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileUserTableViewCell
        cell.coreValueComments1?.text = [indexPath.row].total
        cell.coreValueComments2?.text = [indexPath.row].total
        cell.coreValueComments3?.text = [indexPath.row].total
        cell.coreValueComments4?.text = [indexPath.row].total


        return cell

    }

     else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileCell4", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileUserTableViewCell
        cell.strength1?.text = [indexPath.row].name
        cell.strength2?.text = [indexPath.row].name
        cell.strength3?.text = [indexPath.row].name
        cell.strength4?.text = [indexPath.row].name



        return cell

    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small try of what you can do to serialize your json. I implemented the following code inside a `viewDidLoad()`block to successfully print json data in the xcode console.

```
 let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://*******************")!
    //Your baseURL 
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine")

            do {
                let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                guard let JSONDictionary :NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary else {
                    print("Not a Dictionary")

                    return
                }
              //  print("JSONDictionary! \(JSONDictionary)")

                if let profile = JSONDictionary["profile"] as? NSDictionary {
                    print(profile)


                    //This is where we should begin parsing json into whatever you want to

             let biography = profile["biography"] as? String
                    let designations = profile["designations"] as? String
                    let dob = profile["dob"] as? String
                    let doh = profile["doh"] as? String
                    let email = profile["email"] as? String
                    // do the same for firstname, goals, interests, lastname, location, mentors, phone, skills, speciality

                    print(biography!, designations, dob!)

                    let settings = profile["settings"] as? NSDictionary

                        let enableSMS = settings!.valueForKey("enable_sms") as? String
                        print(enableSMS!)

                    let strengths = profile["strengths"] as? NSArray
                    for eachItem in strengths! {
                        let color = eachItem.valueForKey("color") as? String
                        let description = eachItem.valueForKey("description")
                        let id = eachItem.valueForKey("id")
                        let name = eachItem.valueForKey("name")
                        print(name!, description!, color!, id!)
                    }




                }
            }
            catch let JSONError as NSError {
                print("\(JSONError)")
            }



        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

I hope this helps you. Play around with arrays and dictionaries, and you will be able to pull all the values from your API.

Comment: thank you so much bro!! I have another question though. I am trying to display the json values on my ui. I have attached the code and question on the main post. Could you pls help me out?

Comment: How do you want to display the data in your UI? tableView ?

Comment: Moreover, this is not the exact approach you write codes. This code just serves the purpose of doing something. Please study design pattern and try to follow MVC pattern as this is followed across all areas.

Comment: I've bumped into a new a problem. my design strategy if this works is to create a requestManager Class where I could retrieve the json data from the server and parse it. In my TableViewController class, I will create an instance of the request Manager Class.

Comment: I edited the post. I'm currently unable to correctly match my label to the json Object returned.

Comment: http://szulctomasz.com/how-do-I-build-a-network-layer/ could help you create what you are looking for in case you are still unclear of where to start! I found it a good read.